# INSERT / UPDATE to merge data, when empty data is an empty string

Tags: mysql, insert, update, duplication

Consider a table of some family members:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM some_table;
+--------+--------+--------+
| f_name | l_name | work   |
+--------+--------+--------+
| Meirav | Cohen  | school |
| Dotan  | Cohen  |        |
+--------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Assume that `f_name` is the primary key, and that all columns are `VARCHAR`. Unknown data are not represented as NULL, but rather as an empty string (as can be seen in the `work` column).

I would like to add some data that I know about a person, but I would prefer to not query the database to see what is there but rather have the database merge the extant value with the new values:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO some_table (f_name, l_name, work)
    VALUES ('Dotan', '', 'php')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        f_name = IFNULL(f_name, 'Dotan'),
        l_name = IFNULL(l_name, ''),
        work   = IFNULL(work,   'php');
```

Of course, `IFNULL` doesn't fit the job as it only checks for NULL, not for empty strings. Also, there is the disadvantage that each value to add must appear twice in the SQL.

**Is there any way to have the database merge the data against empty strings?** Also, can it be made such that the strings to insert appear only once in the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid putting values two times in your `INSERT` statement use `VALUES(<column_name>)` function.

> **[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)**
>   You can use the VALUES(col_name) function in the UPDATE clause to
>   refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. In other words, VALUES(col_name) in
>   the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name
>   that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred. This
>   function is especially useful in multiple-row inserts. The VALUES()
>   function is meaningful only in INSERT ... UPDATE statements and
>   returns NULL otherwise.

Unfortunately it's not very clear in your question what is your desired outcome. But assuming that you want update only columns that have `NULL` or empty strings you can do

```
INSERT INTO some_table (f_name, l_name, work)
VALUES ('Dotan', '', 'php')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  f_name = COALESCE(NULLIF(f_name, ''), VALUES(f_name)),
  l_name = COALESCE(NULLIF(l_name, ''), VALUES(l_name)),
  work   = COALESCE(NULLIF(work, ''), VALUES(work));
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dbe3/1)** demo

*If it's not exactly what you want, please consider to post your desired outcome and explain what values under what conditions you want to update*

Comment: @dotancohen You're quite welcome. Good luck :)